# append(html) into $rootElement when $rootElement is window.document

Tags: angularjs

My app is bootstrapped with

```
angular.bootstrap(document, [app.name]);
```

so `$rootElement` is injected as `angular.element(document)`.

Unfortunately, this means that `$rootElement.append("<div>hi</div>")` has no effect.  I have to use `$rootElement.find('body').append`, which works well but assumes that there will be a body tag inside $rootElement.

Is there a way to find out if `$rootElement.append` will work properly?

Answer (score 1):

Short story, even if your root element is html tag:

```
angular.element(document) !== $rootElement
```

Just inject the `$rootElement` and append to it, it would automatically do what you need.

Here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/nelug/2/edit

```
app.run(function($rootElement){
   $rootElement.append("<span>Cool!</span>");
});
```

Comment: Here's your demo bootstrapped as in my question: http://jsbin.com/nelug/3/edit.  I think it is showing that $rootElement *IS* angular.element(document), and it demonstrates my issue - the append doesn't work.